# android: Не могу с фрагмента достучаться на кастомного метода адаптера

Tags: android

Есть 2 фрагмента. Первый запускает сервис, который конектится к инету, читает нужные данные и отправляет броадкастом в другой фрагмент. В адаптере написал метод, который будет добавлять новые элементы в лист и оповещать, что данные изменились. Но с фрагмента, я почему-то его не вижу. Как быть? И насколько хорошая идея передавать данные броадкастом?

```
public class CardsWeatherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardsWeatherAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<CardObject> mCards = new ArrayList<>();
// этот метод должен вызываться с фрагмента
public void addCard(CardObject cardObject){
    mCards.add(cardObject);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView celsius;
    TextView fahrenheit;
    TextView suggestion;
    TextView aqi;
    TextView cityName;
    ImageView cityPicture;
    ImageView aqiColor;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        celsius = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.celsius);
        fahrenheit = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fahrenheit);
        suggestion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.suggestion);
        aqi = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.aqi_value);
        cityName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.city_name);
        cityPicture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.city_picture);
        aqiColor = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.aqi_color);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCards.size();
}
```

}

```
public class CardsFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ACTION = "action";

private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mAdapter. // здесь хочу вызвать метод addCard(), но не получается.
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards, container, false);
    initView(view);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Где код? Только вам известно, как объявлен метод, и почему его не видно из фрагмента. Не задавайте 2 вопроса в одном, это вредно для структуры данного форума. Если вас интересует, хорошо ли передавать данные броадкастом, задайте вопрос отдельно.

Comment: Поправил пост, добавив код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Адаптер у вас объявлен как

```
 private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
```

Очевидно, что у `RecyclerView.Adapter` нет метода `addCard()`. Он есть у `CardsWeatherAdapter`.

Если проще объяснить, то `RecyclerView.Adapter` - это Млекопитающее, а `CardsWeatherAdapter` - это Кошка, которая наследуется от Млекопитающего. И вы объявили переменную типа Млекопитающее, и теперь пытаетесь у него вызвать метод `мурлыкать()`. Но Млекопитающее не умеет мурлыкать! Вы объявили этот метод только у Кошки. 
Чтобы вызвать этот метод, либо объявите поле так:

```
private CardsWeatherAdapter mAdapter;
```

Либо явно приведите адаптер к `CardsWeatherAdapter`:

```
((CardsWeatherAdapter)mAdapter).addCard();
```

Comment: Вы случайно не преподаватель?) У вас отлично получается объяснять)) Спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрБорисов, нет, но когда-то хотел преподавать. Вовремя понял, что я не готов пожертвовать хорошей З/П во имя науки...